# Which fork of jQuery-compatible WMD is the fork to pay attention to?

Tags: jquery, wmd, wmd-editor, wmd-markdown

There seems to be little organization or effort to lead a stable or most up-to-date version of the jQuery-compatible version of WMD.

https://github.com/openlibrary/wmd/network

The latest version of the Open Library branch is almost a year old and has several bugs and odd experiences for automated input.

There are many forks of the Open Library branch, but none of them seem to be a kind of fork meant for general public.

Is there perhaps something better than jQuery WMD or is there a fork that is recommended to use?

Answer (score 0):

If you scroll to the far right on that graph you can see the most up to date forks are:

https://github.com/masterbranch/wmd

https://github.com/ChiperSoft/wmd

Comment: Yes.  I looked at each of the forks thoroughly, and none of them resembled a community effort.  ChiperSoft/wmd "is a fork of WMD for ChiperSoft Systems & NFY Interactive designed for use in CMS engines" and masterbranch/wmd seems to have very few commits from a single author.

Comment: Additionally both ChiperSoft and masterbranchs fork aren't jQuery-compatible.  ChiperSoft fork claims to be a fork of OpenLibrary fork, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @Miz: they are not *incompatible* with jQuery though. WMD is the kind of thing that hardly needs the use jQuery anyway. Also just to point out, the masterbranch version is hardly modified from the original and therefore still full of bugs. The ChiperSoft version seems solid though.

Comment: I'm using the ChiperSoft version now, and it seems to be pretty solid. I submitted a pull request for making a small change to display the correct modifier key on Mac. Haven't heard back yet...  https://github.com/Nilloc/wmd